# Selecting an Object in Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to select an object within an array with `id` condition. In the below img i want to select `[0]`.

[image]

```js
db.users.find({"injury._id": ObjectId("537233061845d2ec10000071")})
```

Thankx for Help.

Comment: Can I please implore you to **stop posting screenshots**. They are horrible to try and read and data ( which you have at least posted some text this time ) is better represented as text so people can actually use it

Comment: With that out of the way. What is your actual question? Do you want to select an array element with an `_id` value or do you want to select the index `0` of an array? And then do what?

Comment: I want to select array element with `_id`...

Comment: You **are** with the query you show above. You mean something else perhaps? Please clarify what you mean by editing your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here that you want to **only** see the selected array element in the document you are searching for. Use projection:

```js
db.users.find(
    { "injury._id": ObjectId("537233061845d2ec10000071")},
    { "injury.$": 1 }
)
```

That just returns the matching element rather than all of them.

If you expect more than **one** match ( unlikely with an ObjectId, but for future reference ) then use the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method instead:

```js
db.users.aggregate([

    // Match documents first, helps reduce the pipeline
    { "$match": {
       "injury._id": ObjectId("537233061845d2ec10000071")
    }},

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$injury" },

    // Actually match the elements
    { "$match": {
       "injury._id": ObjectId("537233061845d2ec10000071")
    }},

    // Group back if you really want arrays
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "injury": { "$push": "$injury" },
        // and use "$first" for any other fields
    }}
])
```

So now you know what to do when you come up against that one as well.

Comment: Thankx...Works good...next time i will try to post it without screenshots..:)

Comment: @Anup Thankyou. And there you also have the basic example included in the answer for when you need to filter **more than one** result from the array.